# SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain

We recently built out a web builder application (WYSIWYG, pre-designed templates, shopping cart etc..). We have been looking at a few different options for SSL certs, even wildcards, for a solution. The problem is we do not want to restart the server every time we have a client who wants to add an SSL to their site (We host the sites). We looked at verisign but according to the sales rep we spoke with at verisign, they would only have the reseller program which does not solve the solution.

Are their any SSL certs that would allow us do do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gracefully restart the server. It won't accept new connections but will wait for the existing connections to close then restart.